# How to add table to store Form data after the Form's creation?

Tags: ms-access

I know my question might frustrate some, but please help if you can. (Yes, I have tried to Google it)

I have created a Form with lots of inputs, but did not base it on a table, now the data is not being stored in one. 
How can I create a table that is basically the saved Datasheet View of the Form ?

All help would be appreciated!

Best,
Desperate Janos

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a table, and add all of the field names of the input controls you created, then manually remap all of the input boxes to the appropriate fields. Sounds tedious but I'm not understanding of the reason to start a form without a table